# Документация по extJS

Tags: extjs, документация

Вобщем-то стыдно задавать такой вопрос, но всё-таки придётся, так как выяснить я это своими усилиями так и не смог. Имеется код на extJS:

```
Ext.MessageBox.show({
title: "Сохранение",
msg: "Имеются изменения. Сохранить?",
buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION
})
```

Смотрю [документацию](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox), ищу в строке поиска метод **show**: Да, нахожу - есть такой, узнаю что он делает и как. Ищу дальше **title** и **battons** - нахожу, все в порядке.
А вот **msg** и **icon** я так и не нашёл... Это при том что код нормально выполняется и отображается как сообщение так и иконка.

Собственно с таким явлением я сталкиваюсь очень часто и это затрудняет изучение фреймворка. В связи с чем вопрос: Где я что упустил? Может есть какие-то общие для всех объектов конфиги, методы, события и т. д. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ изучить extJs открыть в папки fremworka подпапку src там нужный компонент или класс и посмотреть js-ку. Изучение их дает исчерпывающие ответы на все вопросы. ТОлько иногда приходится перелапатить кучу их кода, за то много + можно посмотреть как все реализовано IMHO

Comment: Да, я тоже сейчас склоняюсь к этому варианту. Хотя он и не самый быстрый и простой.

Answer (score 2):

Перейдите по [этой](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html) ссылке. Там живой пример смены иконки. Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я не про иконку. Я в примерах с простора интернета часто вижу возможности, которые мне не удаётся найти в документации. Я думал в доках исчерпывающая информация об этом. Напрашивается вывод: либо не исчерпывающая, либо не умею искать, либо чего-то не понимаю. Вот откуда я мог знать что метод show в данном случае поддерживает конфиг msg?

Answer (score 2):

Msg это алиас - короткое имя. Оно упоминается в самом начале в документации по Ext.MessageBox:

> Utility class for generating different
> styles of message boxes. The alias
> **Ext.Msg** can also be used.

Описание icon есть в описании метода show того же Ext.MessageBox.

Comment: Не нашёл... В общем мне нужно узнать все параметры, которые я могу указать для метода show объекта ExtMsg. Что для этого надо сделать? Только лезть в код, как предлагает @ilyas?

Comment: Вот ссылка на описание метода show():

[http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-show](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-show)

Смотрите раздел **Parameters**

Answer (score 0):

В Ext JS 4.2, в официальной справке, делаем поиск по "MessageBox", первой строкой будет предложена справка по Ext.MessageBox - это то что нам нужно.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox

Там есть раздел Methods, находим в нем метод show. В нем будет описание всех параметров, в том числе и ваши msg, icon и т. д.:

> msg : String A string that will
> replace the existing message box body
> text (defaults to the XHTML-compliant
> non-breaking space character ' ')
>
> icon : String A CSS class that
> provides a background image to be used
> as the body icon for the dialog. One
> can use a predefined icon class:
>
> Ext.MessageBox.INFO
> Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
> Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION
> Ext.MessageBox.ERROR

Что касается понимания Ext JS, то в рунете достаточное количество русскоязычной документации. Самая свежая - [перевод официальной документации Ext JS 4.2](http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/276).